# dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = error produces only warnings

Tags: c#, static-analysis

I'm trying to configure warning CA1062 as an error but I only get warnings.

If I set it to any level lower than `warning` the setting is respected.

Setting any other CAXXXX setting (I tried with CA1805) to `error` does produce an error.

Another interesting observation is that if I comment the rule:

`dotnet_diagnostic.CA1062.severity = error` in my editorconfig I do not see anything at all about this result. Even with `AllEnabledByDefault` set (see below).

What other settings in msbuild files or csproj file could influence this?

The settings I currently have:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>True</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win7-x64;linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <EnableNETAnalyzers>true</EnableNETAnalyzers>
    <AnalysisLevel>5.0</AnalysisLevel>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <AnalysisMode>AllEnabledByDefault</AnalysisMode>

    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>Enable</Nullable>

    <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(SolutionDir)/Metadata/stylecop.json">
      <Link>stylecop.json</Link>
    </AdditionalFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Stylecop.json contains only header information (documentationRules, companyName, copyrightText, headerDecoration).